# Why is read() syscall blocking when I pass in a invalid buffer pointer?

Tags: c, linux, io, filesystems, system-calls

Here is my code snippet `read(STDIN, NULL, 10)` executed on Linux-2.6.32.431. I assumed it would return immediadely after I'd browsed the read() syscall's source code:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(read, unsigned int, fd, char __user *, buf, size_t, count)
{
    struct file *file;
    ssize_t ret = -EBADF;
    int fput_needed;

    file = fget_light(fd, &fput_needed);
    if (file) {
        loff_t pos = file_pos_read(file);
        ret = vfs_read(file, buf, count, &pos);
        file_pos_write(file, pos);
        fput_light(file, fput_needed);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

and

```
ssize_t vfs_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
{
    ssize_t ret;

    if (!(file->f_mode & FMODE_READ))
        return -EBADF;
    if (!file->f_op || (!file->f_op->read && !file->f_op->aio_read))
        return -EINVAL;
    if (unlikely(!access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, buf, count))) //I suppose it should return here
        return -EFAULT;
    ...
}
```

However, it got blocked. After I typed in some characters and hitted return, this program consumed one character and returned while the remaining characters inputed into the terminal.

My question is:

1. why did the read() syscall get blocked?
2. why did the remaining characters get inputed into the terminal.

Comment: With `STDIN`, do you mean `STDIN_FILENO` file descriptor or the C `stdin` `FILE` stream?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I mean STDIN_FILENO but it should be clear in the context of syscall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `access_ok` does not do exactly what its name implies.

From [the comments in arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h#L69):

```
/**
 * access_ok: - Checks if a user space pointer is valid
 * @type: Type of access: %VERIFY_READ or %VERIFY_WRITE.  Note that
 *        %VERIFY_WRITE is a superset of %VERIFY_READ - if it is safe
 *        to write to a block, it is always safe to read from it.
 * @addr: User space pointer to start of block to check
 * @size: Size of block to check
 *
 * Context: User context only.  This function may sleep.
 *
 * Checks if a pointer to a block of memory in user space is valid.
 *
 * Returns true (nonzero) if the memory block may be valid, false (zero)
 * if it is definitely invalid.
 *
 * Note that, depending on architecture, this function probably just
 * checks that the pointer is in the user space range - after calling
 * this function, memory access functions may still return -EFAULT.
 */
```

The comments appear to be accurate; on x86, if you trace the definition of `access_ok`, [you will find](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h#L54) it just checks (essentially) whether `addr + size > user_addr_max()`. In particular, it returns "true" for a NULL pointer.

So you have to trace `vfs_read` a little further, into the call to `file->f_op->read()`, which is presumably invoking the `read` function for the TTY driver, which is presumably where it is blocking.

(Note that POSIX guarantees nothing when you pass a NULL pointer to `read`, so I would advise not doing that.)

[Update]

For your second question, it's the same reason this sequence reads one character and then passes the rest to the terminal:

```
$ head -c 1 > /dev/null
lalala
$ alala
alala: command not found
```

All I did was input "lalala" to the `head` command. Your program is presumably consuming one character of TTY input, terminating (crashing), and then the rest of the input to the TTY is being consumed by the shell after your program exits.

Comment: Correct! How about the second question?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [`read`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) manual page you will see that:

> **EFAULT** `buf` is outside your accessible address space.

A `NULL` pointer is still within the accessible address space of all processes. Writing to, or dereferencing, a `NULL` pointer leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), but it's still a valid address.

So the `read` call blocks because there's no input to be read. When there is, the process will most likely crash.